# Unity: Build looks different then gameview: runtime reflection probes not working correctly

Tags: unity, rendering, lighting, realtime, reflection-rendering

Im having a really hard time figuring out how to configure my reflection probes to update in runtime once I build. The game port view looks totally different than the build view. Ive tried turning off baked GI in the lighting > scene panel, and unchecking "auto" under "other settings" but keep getting an error message "baking lighting data asset failed" when I try to build the light maps. Maybe this is not the right way to solve the problem? Has anyone else encountered this and figured it out?[image: error message]

[image: scene settings]